# Secure sonarwhal passing adsbygoogle.js usage

Tags: security

Sonarwhal is dinging me for my usage of Google ads. Is there away to get the [sri rules](https://sonarwhal.com/docs/user-guide/rules/rule-sri/) and `origin` rules to pass?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For now, the only way to pass those rules is using the CLI.

You will find all the documentation to install and use it in [github](https://github.com/webhintio/hint)

Don't be surprised if you see that now it is call webhint hehehe.

Using the CLI you can ignore some URLs using the configuration file. To do so, you need to add this configuration to your configuration file:

```
{
  ...
  "ignoredUrls" : [ 
    {
      "domain" : "^https?://adservice\\.google\\.co\\.uk/.*",
      "rules" : ["*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

- `domain` is a regex that match the url you want to ignore.
- `rules` rules is an array with the rules you want to ignore the url or `*` if you want to ignore all the rules.

You can add as many domains as you want.